How to Create an LSTM in PyTorch that Outputs Fixed Parameters Over Time?
I have a "hybrid" model in PyTorch, which is a mix of a conceptual hydrological model and an LSTM, working as described:

I'm trying to create an LSTM that outputs one set of parameters over time, meaning that the parameters do not vary for each time step. (The conceptual model generates the river flow over time based on the parameters and precipitation).
However, I think I am doing this in a clumsy way and can't see another way to do it. Below is a snippet of my model.
# Parameters
#network_params = {
#  "input_size": len(attributes) + len(forcing) - 1,  # Tamanho da entrada (número de atributos + forçantes - data)
#  "no_of_layers": 1,  # Número de camadas da LSTM
#  "sequence_length": 180,  # Comprimento da sequência para a LSTM 180
#  "warmup_period": 365,  # Período de aquecimento
#  "batches_to_update": 20,  # Número de lotes para atualizar os parâmetros
#  "hidden_size": 64,  # Tamanho oculto do modelo
#  "no_of_epochs": 20,  # Número de épocas de treinamento
#  "drop_out": 0.4,  # Dropout do modelo
#  "learning_rate": 0.01,  # Taxa de aprendizado
#  'set_forget_gate': 3,  # Configuração da porta de esquecimento
#  "adapt_learning_rate_epoch": 5,  # Épocas para ajustar a taxa de aprendizado
#  "adapt_gamma_learning_rate": 0.8  # Fator de ajuste da taxa de aprendizado
#}

# Class to create the hybrid model. Here is where I combine the LSTM network with the hydrological model

class Hybrid_Model(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self, network_params, cuda):
        
        super().__init__()

        self.num_features = network_params['input_size']
        self.hidden_units = network_params['hidden_size']
        self.num_layers   = network_params['no_of_layers']
        self.cuda0 = cuda

        # Create LSTM network
        
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size = network_params['input_size'], 
                            hidden_size = network_params['hidden_size'], 
                            batch_first = True,
                            num_layers = network_params['no_of_layers'])

        
        self.dropout = torch.nn.Dropout(network_params['drop_out'])
        
        #out_features should be changed depending on the number of parameters!!!
        
        self.linear = nn.Linear(in_features=network_params['hidden_size'], out_features=4)
        
        # Create hydrological model
        
        self.SHM = SHM_dynamic_parameters()
           
    def forward(self, X_LSTM, X_SHM, initial_states, warmup_period=0):
        
        # Initialize hidden state with zeros
        batch_size = X_LSTM.shape[0]
        
        h0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_units).requires_grad_().to(self.cuda0)
        c0 = torch.zeros(self.num_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_units).requires_grad_().to(self.cuda0)
        
        # run LSTM: The LSTM predicts the values that will be used by the hydrological model as parameters. 
        # It predicts the all the timesteps at once! This means that if I am running by hydrological model 
        # for 2 years, the LSTM will predict the values of all the parameters for the 2 years at once. 
        
        _, (hn, _) = self.lstm(X_LSTM, (h0, c0))
        
        out = hn[-1]
        
        out = self.dropout(out)
        out = self.linear(out)
        out = torch.sigmoid(out)
        
        out_copy = out.clone()

        # warmup period to stabilize the internal initial_states (buckets) of the hydrological model
        
        if warmup_period > 0:
            with torch.no_grad():
                _, _, initial_states = self.SHM(X_SHM=X_SHM[0:warmup_period, :], 
                                                 out_LSTM=out_copy.unsqueeze(1),  # Adiciona uma dimensão de tempo
                                                 initial_states=initial_states, 
                                                 cuda=self.cuda0)
                
                initial_states = initial_states[-1, :]
                
        # run the model
        q_out, parameters, new_states = self.SHM(X_SHM=X_SHM[warmup_period:, :], 
                                                 out_LSTM=out_copy.unsqueeze(1),  # Adiciona uma dimensão de tempo
                                                 initial_states=initial_states, 
                                                 cuda=self.cuda0)

        return q_out, parameters, new_states

Any help will be welcome. If you need more information, I can edit the question.

I'm no expert in your domain, but seeing this in a general machine learning context, here are some options that came to mind

Using the last output of the LSTM: The LSTM produces one final output after seeing the whole sequence and this can be fed as inputs into your other conceptual model after some transformations (through an FC layer, etc that you have). This will be one fixed set of parameters for the whole sequence that you can feed into your next model.

The output of the LSTM is given like this in Pytorch
output, (h_n, c_n) = self.lstm(...)


Instead of using h_n[-1] like you are in your code, I think it makes more sense to use output[-1] because that is the main prediction of the LSTM for the last timestep. (I haven't worked out the dimensional compatibility in your code though). This answer has a nice diagram of the difference between the output and hidden states.

You can apply some form of pooling (like mean) on the time series outputs of the LSTM, if you start to see that information from earlier inputs in a series is not being retained.

pooled_output = torch.mean(lstm_output, dim=1)


Instead of an LSTM you can use the attention mechanism to learn a single representation for the whole series and feed that into the conceptual model.


Thank you for the comments. After posting this question, I ended up implementing both alternatives you proposed. However, I am now somewhat dissatisfied with the model's performance. A common optimization algorithm (like SCE) has been performing much better. Perhaps the issue lies in using the "attention mechanism" you mentioned. I will study it further.
